# jQuery UI Dialog - Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to fix a dialog. The `sticky` property sticks it, but I need to fix the dialog where the div is.

Basically I need the dialog behave like an regular `div` (if I set it inside an table, it stays there. Not in the middle of the screen).

I know this is related with position effect, but I can't figure out how to make this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using jQuery BlockUI instead?  It has element blocking, and I think that's what you're after here.  From what I remember about jQuery UI, the positioning is based off the viewport, not the page itself. http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Comment: The UI dialog position can be anywhere, relative to anything, it sounds like he doesn't want a modal at all though (which blockUI also is).

Comment: That's right. I don't want the modal to start with position top, left, right, bottom, center, center.
I was trying to set the modal position where "she is in the page". I've thought about put the div of modal inside other div, then get the other div position through javascript and set the position of modal equal.
But i don't know if jQuery doesn't have an option to do this.